# What the difference between 賃金 and 給料?

Tags: word-choice, words

I was reading 二銭銅貨 from 江戸川乱歩, and the words 給料 and 賃金 occurred :

> 芝区のさる大きな電機工場の職工**給料**日の出来事であった。

I understand 給料日 as the "pay day", or the day the worker receive their salary.

> 十数名の賃銀計算係が、五千人近い職工のタイム・カードから、それぞれ一ヶ月の賃銀を計算して、山と積まれた給料袋の中へ、当日銀行から引き出された、大トランクに一杯もあろうという、二十円、十円、五円などの紙幣を汗だくになって、詰め込んでいるさなかに、事務所の玄関へ一人の紳士が訪れた。

In that sentence, 賃銀 is the old form of 賃金.

What I don't understand is the difference between 給料 and 賃金 in that context. My dictionary both translate them as "salary".

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer, considering that no one else has posted an answer, and considering the advice that [Comments are not for answers](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/593/comments-are-not-for-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Subjectively, my sense is that [賃金]{ちんぎん} is closer in nuance to the English term *wages* (money paid for a specific unit of work, not necessarily ongoing), while [給料]{きゅうりょう} is closer to *salary* (money paid for a specific unit of time, usually as part of an ongoing contract). Much as in English, I've seen a certain amount of overlap between these two.  That said, I'm not a native speaker of Japanese, and I may have gotten the wrong end of the stick at some point.

User [aguijonazo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/43676/) also commented:

> I agree with @EiríkrÚtlendi. And [賃金]{ちんぎん} sounds more technical. It is used in such terms as [賃金交渉]{ちんぎんこうしょう} (between employers and unions), [賃金水準]{ちんぎんすいじゅん} (of a particular industry, country, etc.), [賃金未払い]{ちんぎんみはらい}, etc. It is not commonly used for individual payments nowadays, not least by those on the receiving side.